# modelErrors Property from json response is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to parse json response. The JSON response is coming in responseText property
First of all i am getting response from Json as follows:

```
{"Success":false,"Error":true,"ErrorType":1,"ModelErrors":{"Name":"\u0027Name\u0027 must not be empty.","Owner":"\u0027Owner\u0027 must not be empty.","Email":"\u0027Email\u0027 must not be empty.","Password":"\u0027Password\u0027 must not be empty.","Size":"Please provide a valid Number"}}
```

when i do `console.log(response.responseText)` i get the above output on console.

Now I am catching this response in this function. Everything work fine in success but when error block executes in case of error I get ModelErrors property undefined. Here is my function

```
 $("form").on('submit', function () {
        var form = $('.form');


        var url = form.attr('action');
        var formData = form.serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: formData,
            success: function (response) {


                if (response.Success==true) {
                    console.log(response.Success);

                    showMsg(response.Message);
                    //alert(response.Message);
                }

                //alert(data);
            },
            error: function (response) {

                console.log(response.responseText);

                if (response.responseText.Error === true)

                {

                    var modelErrors = response.responseText.ModelErrors;

                    console.log(modelErrors);
                    console.log("Check "+modelErrors);

                }

            },

            cache: false
        });
    });
```

I tried different solutions but i could not figure out where i am doing wrong. Please help me in this regard. Thanks

Comment: May be issue in `\u0027Name\u0027`. Remvoe `\u0027` from your `modelerrors` and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse the JSON

```js
var json='{"Success":false,"Error":true,"ErrorType":1,"ModelErrors":{"Name":"\u0027Name\u0027 must not be empty.","Owner":"\u0027Owner\u0027 must not be empty.","Email":"\u0027Email\u0027 must not be empty.","Password":"\u0027Password\u0027 must not be empty.","Size":"Please provide a valid Number"}}';
var tmp=JSON.parse(json);
console.log(tmp.ModelErrors);
```